# Ansible: no hosts matched

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to execute my first remote shell script on Ansible. I've first generated and copied the SSH keys. Here is my yml file:

```
---
- name: Ansible remote shell
  hosts: 192.168.10.1
  user: myuser1
  become: true
  become_user: jboss
  tasks:
    - name: Hello server
      shell: /home/jboss/script.sh
```

When launching the playbook however, the outcome is "no hosts matched":

```
ansible-playbook setup.yml 

PLAY [Ansible remote shell
******************************************** 
skipping: no hosts matched

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************
```

I've tried also using the host name (instead of the IP address), however nothing changed. Any help ?

Comment: The same issue. Why doesn't ansible find an inventory file even though the ansible.cfg is defined with the inventory file path. I'm trying to run a playbook from the same dir where the ansible.cfg is located. By the way, `ansible-playbook --version` shows my config file, which means it should work.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You need to define a host inventory.

The default path for this is `/etc/ansible/hosts` (as also stated by helloV).

For a minimal example you can also specify an inventory in the command line:

```
ansible-playbook setup.yml -i 192.168.10.1,
```

The trailing comma makes it a list, such that ansible parses it directy. Otherwise you can run

```
ansible-playbook setup.yml -i myinventory
```

where `myinventory` is a file listing your hosts.

Comment: Thanks for the kind reply and for the minimal example from the command line

Comment: Can I keep both host inventories- /etc/ansible/hosts and also specify -i hostip ?

Comment: I cant find my `/etc/ansible/hosts`. It keeps telling me No directory found

Comment: can you just use "localhost"?

Comment: just had to add `,` after IP

Comment: This "-i <host>" argument is exactly what i was looking for. It worked well. Thanks.

Answer (score 16):

Ansible doesn't know anything about your host. If it is in dynamic inventory, you can pass the inventory script using -i option or edit `/etc/ansible/hosts` and add an entry for your host like:

```
[myhost]
192.168.10.1
```

and specify the host in the playbook as:

```
hosts: myhost
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply

Comment: @helloV is this a .ini file or .yml?

Answer (score 0):

we have to create an Inventory file in ansible there we need to give the location of IP address file for 
create a file by name **/ip.txt** 
And provide the path of the above-created file in your inventory